# Getting response as org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@52dd3be8 in multipartResquest while uploading image

Tags: java, android

I m uploading Base 64 in header of the service,I am getting the status line as 200 OK but the response I am getting as org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@52dd3be8
I should get the response as "../Img_Category/1_1_671.png".

Here is my code.

try {

```
        String str = twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd;
        String str2 = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"jsonFile\"";
        String str3 = "Content-Type: application/json";
        String str4 = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imgName\"";
        String str5 = "Content-Type: image/jpeg";
        String str6 = twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens;

        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray,
                Base64.DEFAULT);

        String StrTotal = str + str2 + "\r\n" + str3 + "\r\n" + "\r\n"
                + str + str4 + "\r\n" + str5 + "\r\n" + "\r\n"
                + encodedImage + "\r\n" + str;

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String boundary = "-------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+ boundary);
        httpPost.addHeader("ImgSrc", encodedImage);

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(StrTotal);
        se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        Log.i("response", response + "");

        int responseString = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        Log.i("responseString", responseString + "");

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        getResponseText = entity.toString();
        Log.i("getResponseText", getResponseText);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("uploadImageException", e.toString());
    }
```

Please help me in solving this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should get response content like this:

```
private static String getStringContent(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "utf-8"));
        String body;
        String content = "";

        while ((body = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            content += body + "\n";
        }
        return content.trim();
    }
```